# Why My ReactQuill lose focus whenever I type inside React router 6 after navigating from other page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-quill

I don't know why my editor loses focus while I type each time. Steps to reproduce

1. type something in ReactQuill (atm it's normal),
2. navigate to page b
3. will detect url change, and pop up Prompt to let the user setState in Parent component.
4. now in page b, we switch back to page a
5. this time, every time I type in editor, the editor lose focus, and shows warning
   in console

> addRange(): The given range isn't in document.

PS: If I put the ReactQuill outside the Routes, it works without any losing focus issue.
react version 16, react-quill 1.3.5

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
 ...
render() {
<Routes>
  <Route element={<Layout />} >
    <Route path="/a" element={(
       <PromptWrapper>
         <ReactQuill
            style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}
            minHeight={100}
            innerRef={(ref) => this.aboutUsEditor = ref}
            theme="core"
            value={aboutUsDescription}
            onChange={(text, delta, source) =>
              this.handleChangeEditor(text, delta, source,)
            }
            modules={{
              toolbar: false,
            }}
          />
       </PromptWrapper>
    )}/>
    <Route path="/b" element={(
       <div>
         Page 2
       </div>
    )}/>
  </Routes>
```

Is there anything I should be aware ? Thanks

Comment: Would it be possible to create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Hi Drew, my project is complicated, actually even the ReactQuill is another component wrapped in reactQuill. So I just want somebody to tell me the clues or ideas, thanks.

Comment: Ah, well without a [mcve] it'll likely be difficult for anyone to say why navigating away and back to `"/a"` causes the `ReactQuill` component to behave oddly. I do see this [post](/questions/63597028/react-quill-addrange-the-given-range-isnt-in-document?rq=1) over in the related section.